Should we hold new moderator elections?
We elected a new moderator more than 1 year ago. However, this moderator is rarely active and the last time he was active on the site was more than 1 month ago and this has happened several times, I've noticed.
I think moderators should be users that visit the site at least once every day or two days, even if the site isn't that active, and take action whenever the community doesn't (although maybe some will argue against this because they think moderators should do as little as possible and maybe that's why it's not a problem for them to have inactive moderators).
So, I think we should hold new moderator elections and maybe remove the inactive moderator. I don't know exactly the rules (i.e. if a moderator can be removed because he's rarely active), but I don't think that keeping an inactive moderator in his role makes sense.
There are other people that could moderate our site, including myself, although I am not sure I'd run again for the new role. Some of them might be more active and as or more competent.
Disclaimer: I was once a moderator here and I care about this site and it remains healthy.

I'm with Mithical - moderation is happening, so unless there's a problem that isn't being handled, I don't see much of an issue. To be fair, I'm one of the people who isn't on the site every day or two, but if the community wants a more active hand, I can make it a point to start checking in more often. But up to this point, the available evidence suggests that there isn't an urgent need to do so.

Yes. In my post, I was indeed referring to you, but I know it's not a good idea to refer to people directly. Anyway, you had not visited the site for than 1 month and this has happened more than once I think. Suddenly, you're back, maybe because someone contacted you, or by random chance you visited the site to answer this question specifically. But based on your profile you're rarely active on the site. Moderation is still happening, I suppose, but does make sense for you to be a mod if you're rarely active here and maybe there are other people that could be more active and moderate?

If you still want to moderate and you visit the site every a couple of days, I think it's fine you're still a mod, but if you visit the site once every month, I don't think it makes sense you continue to be a mod. That's my view, because, like I said, I think mods should be users that visit the site frequently.

The question is less about the specific activity of specific moderators and more about whether or not moderation is actually happening as necessary. The activity level of specific moderators is generally a matter between the mod team and Stack Exchange staff. Outside of Stack Overflow, there are no hard activity requirements for moderators, although moderators who are inactive for six months or more are usually prodded to either become active or step down.
Currently, there are 2 pending flags on AI.SE, both custom moderator flags that require some subject matter expertise. Other flags, both custom flags and standard flags, have been handled generally within hours to days. Over the past month, the average flag handling time is slightly over four hours.
Does it feel like moderation is not happening on AI.SE to the extent that it should? Are there significant delays in handling issues? I personally don't get the impression that there are; I think that flags are generally handled within a reasonable timeframe. The review queues do tend to sit a little longer, but that's a task for the community at large and not just moderators.
I will admit that my personal activity level has dropped recently. I've started university and have other things going on, which means I haven't been as active as in the past. Do we need to elect another moderator to supplement? I'm not sure - my impression has been that moderation is happening on a reasonable time scale. I'm open to hearing other perspectives, though.

I didn't say moderation is not happening. I said that it doesn't make sense to have an inactive moderator when someone more active can participate in the community. So, we should hold moderator elections. One of the moderators rarely contributed to the community since they were elected. What sense does it make to keep them as a mod?

My point is that generally the activity levels of individual moderators is a matter between the mod team and SE staff, not for the community at large. Whether or not moderation is happening as it should is a matter for the community at large.

You mean should "not" be a matter for the community at large? Well, maybe that is the case right now, but the community can elect moderators why can't they also say "Ok, this moderator is not doing the job we expected them to do and so it should be removed". It's not a big deal because moderation still happens to some extent, but I am sharing my opinion that it does not make sense to keep an inactive moderator in their role so maybe we should replace the inactive mods.

That's also why regular elections should maybe be hold here too so that the community is kept "alive". I know that in general a mod might not be removed until they step down, but this kind goes against democracy, but then you can argue that Stack Exchange is not really a democracy where normal users can contribute as much as mods or staff.
